# ANDROID: Pixel Coordinates Differ in phones when drawing a simple shape. FIX THIS BUT HOW? Adjust hardcoded pixels so it looks the same on each phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-canvas, pixel, screen-resolution

So I am a near noob at programming android, and i am still learning it.

I have created a small 2D spaceship game, where you have to dodge the oncoming stars by moving your finger. This game works almost perfectly on my emulator, but when played on other phones (like my friend's), it is messed up.

First of all the spaceship looks too big on his phone, and so do the stars, (not like on my emulator). And my written text coordinates seem to be off as well.

I believe the problem has something to do with pixels, and adjusting them with each phone but how?

Thank you for helping me,

Below is my long code, if you want to go through it, though it's unnecessary...

**Please if you can, show me an example of how you do it, so show me what you put in the coordinates when drawing a simple rectangle for example...Thanks A lot**

```
package com.zunairgames.zunair;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class GFXSurface extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

MyBringBackSurface ourSurfaceView;
float x, y;
boolean testingFinger=false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ourSurfaceView = new MyBringBackSurface(this);
    ourSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    x=0;
    y=0;

     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(ourSurfaceView);//ourSurfaceView
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSurfaceView.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    ourSurfaceView.resume();
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    x= event.getX();
    y= event.getY();

     if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
         testingFinger=true;
         return true;
     }
     if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
         testingFinger=false;
         return false;
     }



    return false;
}

public class MyBringBackSurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
//vertical
SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
Canvas canvas = (Canvas) ourHolder;
Thread ourThread = null;
boolean isRunning=false;
int screenHeight;
int screenWidth;

Random random = new Random ();
boolean loadStuff = false;

int posX=0;
int posY=0;
int posWidth=100;
int posHeight=100;


int numStars=4;
int starX[]=new int[numStars];
int starY[]=new int[numStars];
int starSpeed[]=new int[numStars];


int score=0;
int backgroundY=0;


Bitmap spaceship;
Bitmap background;
Bitmap starPic;


public MyBringBackSurface(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context);
    ourHolder= getHolder();


}

public void pause(){
    isRunning=false;
    while(true){
        try {
            ourThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
    ourThread=null;
}
public void resume(){
    isRunning=true;
    ourThread=new Thread(this);
    ourThread.start();
}



public int round(double d){
    double dAbs = Math.abs(d);
    int i = (int) dAbs;
    double result = dAbs - (double) i;
    if(result<0.5){
        return d<0 ? -i : i;            
    }else{
        return d<0 ? -(i+1) : i+1;          
    }
}

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();

    int height = bm.getHeight();

    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;

    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // create a matrix for the manipulation

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);   
    // recreate the new Bitmap

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

    return resizedBitmap;

    }
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    while(isRunning){
        if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())continue;

         canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();

         if(loadStuff==false){
                for (int i=0; i <numStars; i++){
                    starY[i]=-random.nextInt(200);
                    starX[i]=random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-50);
                    starSpeed[i]=1+random.nextInt(5);
                }
                 spaceship = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.spaceship);
                 background  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.background);
                 starPic  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.tile);

                 spaceship = getResizedBitmap(spaceship,100,100);
                 background= getResizedBitmap(background,(canvas.getHeight())*2,(canvas.getWidth()));
                 starPic= getResizedBitmap(starPic,50,50);

                     backgroundY=-(canvas.getHeight());

                     x=canvas.getWidth()/2;
                     y=canvas.getHeight()/2;
                loadStuff=true;
                }


        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setTextSize(40);

        for (int i=0; i <numStars; i++){
            starY[i]+=starSpeed[i];

            if(starY[i]>canvas.getHeight()){
                starY[i]=-random.nextInt(200);
                starX[i]=random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-50);
                starSpeed[i]=starSpeed[i]+random.nextInt(2);
            }

            if(x+posWidth>starX[i]&&x<starX[i]+50 && y+posHeight>starY[i]&&y<starY[i]+50){
                starY[i]=-random.nextInt(200);
                starX[i]=random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-50);
                starSpeed[i]=1+random.nextInt(10);
                score++;
            }
        }

        backgroundY++;
        if(backgroundY>-10){
            backgroundY=-canvas.getHeight();
    }
        canvas.drawRGB( 3, 120, 12);
        canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0,backgroundY, null);

        for (int i=0; i <numStars; i++){
              canvas.drawBitmap(starPic,starX[i] , starY[i],null);

        }
        canvas.drawText("SCORE : "+ score  + "DENSITY :"+ canvas.getDensity(),0, 100, paint);





        canvas.drawBitmap(spaceship, x,y, null);


        ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

    //72
    }
```

Comment: did u manage to resolve this issue?...I facing the same where my rect goes out of screen.

Answer (score 0):

When programatically setting widths and pixel locations you need to make sure you take into account the screen density which varies from device to device.

So you figure you do your calculations in "Density Independent Pixels" (DIP or DP) and then convert them to real pixels using a formula like below before setting it on the component.

```
public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));       
    return px;
}
```

Further reading at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels

Comment: So, for example if I have to draw a rectangle at (13,26) with a width of 100, and height of 100, will i have to do something like this???        canvas.drawRect(dpToPx(13),dpToPx(26),dpToPx(100),dpToPx(100));

Comment: Also, will this affect performance of my app in any way, if i use your method in my loop?

Comment: Sounds right. I wouldn't expect it to impact performance considering it's a one off calculation before you are about to do bitmap manipulation. The displayMetrics.xdpi and displayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT shouldn't change so you could refactor it as a precalculated scaling value if you like.

Answer (score 0):

you can override this method and the devices width and height will go to it when you start the activity and scale properly

```
 @Override
public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
{
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    screenW = w;
    screenH = h;




}
```

Comment: So a couple of things...I don't get why we're multiplying by "1.28" and i don't get how this will help my images stay the same...And we didn't even use Oldw and Oldh given in this method...please explain to me. thanks

Comment: sorry that was just in there from when i used it, i edited it, but the first two are width int w, and height h, of the device you are using, if you scale the bitmaps based on the width and height of the device according to the actual screen its running ons width and height it will come out the same for different size screens

Comment: So basically we can determine the scale by dividing the new width by old width..And then, we basically take our picture's width & height and times them by the scale to determine the new proper picture....is that right? just making sure (i  am new to this)...

Comment: example: if we want to do canvas.drawRect(20,20,100,100);, then we basically do this : int scale = screenW/oldw; canvas.drawRect(20*scale, 20*scale, 100*scale, 100*scale); ?? will this work for bitmaps as well??? Thankyou so much

Comment: no, it runs once when the app is started, so int w, is the width of the device, i just completely ignore oldw and oldh, so "h" and "w" is the width and height of the device, if you save them in variables like shown, then say you devide any device in whatever units, say 6, "w"/6 could be the width of your spaceship, and that would be the same on all devices

Comment: im pretty sure you can use it in your MyBringBackSurface class because it extends SurfaceView and SurfaceView extends View, its a method you can override from the View class

Comment: your welcom, i think the oldw and oldh is for when the view changes orientation, or size like if you keep filling a view with something, but in your case your using the view as the whole screen